# How can I page through one document at a time using Blaze in Meteor without multiple mongo queries

Tags: mongodb, meteor, pagination, meteor-blaze

I have a mongo database of task documents where tasks look something like this:

```
{
  "name" : "Clean room",
  "points" : 5
}
```

I would like a simple interface where users can have a carousel of sorts, where they can cycle through a rolodex of their tasks but only see one task at a time.

I've thought about doing some sort of mongo query such as

```
Tasks.find({}).limit(1).skip(index);
```

but that seems very inefficient, both for number of DB requests and in time the user needs for the request to be made.

Is there a way that perhaps a query could return a cursor object, and then show only the current indexed task? I would hesitate to change the cursor into a local array because I would lose reactivity. Bonus points if I don't have to install a pagination or reactive-array/dict library, but I welcome the suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about just deciding which element to show with an additional helper?

```
<template name="myTemplate">
  {{#each tasks}}
    {{#if taskVisible @index}}
      {{> oneTask}}
    {{/if}}
  {{/each}}
</template>
```

Where `tasks` is a helper that returns a cursor and `oneTask` is the template you want to use to display an individual task.

Then it's just an issue of writing the `taskVisible` helper which decides if a given task is visible or not.

Comment: Perfect! I actually have something just like that elsewhere in my code. I just didn't think to implement it here.